# Show pins on Image view in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to add a pin on UIImageView at particular coordinates in ios. I am not using mapkit. I have to do it on imageview. example picture is attached.

[image]

Please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple solution, you can try it.
Every pin is a UIButton with "pin" image. You can add a pin at particular location in UIImageView by using frame or autolayout.
To show the windowview on top of pin, you can add action to each pin and detect pin by add tag or by another property.